# Unhandled exception: Exception: Flutter failed to create a directory at "/Users/akyadav/.config/flutter"

Tags: macos, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and have recently started learning how to Develop UI interfaces. I had everything set up, and today I tried to upgrade to Flutter 2.0 (I understand I wouldn't need to use all of its features rn). I was constantly getting the following error everytime I run flutter upgrade or flutter doctor (even flutter doctor -v), it just doesn't work and has me stumped. Can anybody help me how to get it working?

```
Unhandled exception:
Exception: Flutter failed to create a directory at "/Users/akyadav/.config/flutter". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _throwFileSystemException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:749:3)
#2      _handlePosixException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:697:3)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:561:7)
#4      ErrorHandlingDirectory.createSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:408:12)
#5      new Config (package:flutter_tools/src/base/config.dart:33:17)
#6      runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:146:21)
#7      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:41)
#8      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:311:23)
#9      AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#10     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#11     config (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:47:30)
#12     getBuildDirectory (package:flutter_tools/src/build_info.dart:673:48)
#13     defaultDepfilePath (package:flutter_tools/src/bundle.dart:29:55)
#14     new BuildBundleCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_bundle.dart:24:42)
#15     new BuildCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build.dart:33:19)
#16     main.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:102:5)
#17     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and reinstalled flutter and worked for me. I get the solution from here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67840.